# SMTP Finding Host/User/Pass to Receive Emails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm attempting to use PHPMailer to set up my email to receive emails/messages via a contact form on my website. I'm having trouble setting it up. Submitting the contact form calls this php file `sendemail.php`:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
                'email' => 'myRealEmail@yahoo.com', // Your Email Address
                'name' => 'My Name' // Your Name
            );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

// Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = 'your-recaptcha-secret-key'; // Your reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.yourdomain.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = "yourname@yourdomain.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

        $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
        $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
        $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
        $service = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service'] : '';
        $subject = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] : '';
        $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
                $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
            }
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $service = isset($service) ? "Service: $service<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $service $message $referrer";

            // Runs only when File Field is present in the Contact Form
            if ( isset( $_FILES['template-contactform-file'] ) && $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['name'] );
            }

            // Runs only when reCaptcha is present in the Contact Form
            if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
                $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

                $g_response = json_decode( $response );

                if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
                    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
                    die;
                }
            }

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
            else:
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

Which calls this `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * PHP Version 5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2014 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
 */
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the initial php file it was using 'mail()' which I switched to be SMTP now. However, I've never used this and am very confused on how to use it. As you can see from the template, Host has: `mail.yourdomain.com` -- Is that my website domain, my email service providers domain? Next it asks for a Username and Password. Where do I find those? What are they the User/Pass for? I'm just trying to set this up for my regular email address, not one generated by cPanel or something like that. Thanks for the help.

I've done a few things now like pinging yahoo and my domain's server to get the address, I think I got that? But not entirely sure which is the correct one. I know the port should be like 587 too I think. For Yahoo, I pinged their server or whatever via console so would the following be what I fill in:

```
Host = "mta7.am0.yahoodns.net"
// Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
Username = "myYahooEmail@yahoo.com"
Password = "myYahooPassword"
```

I tried the above and I still get this:

> Email could not be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again
>   later.
>
> Reason: SMTP connect() failed.

Another question along the same line is if this is your Password for your email account, what happens if you have 2step Authentication or something like that? Yahoo (the email I'd like to send messages to. I have GMail as well, but ignoring that for now) doesn't actually even let me sign in with my Password anymore. They send me a text w/ a code every time someone tries to log in on my account.

Edit:
TRied this code already via the link posted in the comment below. I suppose I might have implemented it wrong?:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "---@yahoo.com";
$mail->Password = "---";
```

Via Synchro's comments, I added: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` instead and that made my contact form never submit (just keeps spinning like it wants to send the message).

Comment: Strangely enough, [Yahoo tells you what to use for their servers](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html).

Comment: @Synchro Strangely enough, I've already used it! Unless this is incorrect? `$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "----@yahoo.com";
$mail->Password = "--------------";` Editing OP with this

Comment: `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` won't work with `Port = 587`; Set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`. If you want to see what's going on while you're trying to fix this, set `SMTPDebug = 3`.

Comment: @Synchro Okay will try that, I've done tls already - but not all of them together I don't think (also haven't done debug=3, not sure what it does this is template)! Just tested it and now my form never sends just spins forever. Interesting, I guess/maybe that's a start? Do you need anymore info from me to potentially help with this error? Can post the form if necessary, but pretty sure that's not the issue

Comment: I changed it to debug = 0 with the same code above and it failed to connect... :/

Comment: Try the tests in the troubleshooting guide to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146194/discussion-between-john-barr-and-synchro).